# error in flutter path_provider installation

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to use path_provider package in flutter.
I installed this library on my project, but after running the project, it gives me the following error.
When I install other libraries that use this package, I still get the same error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider_android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-7.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.1/gradle-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find lint-model-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-model/30.3.1/lint-model-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find builder-7.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.3.1/builder-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find manifest-merger-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/30.3.1/manifest-merger-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find sdk-common-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/30.3.1/sdk-common-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find sdklib-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/30.3.1/sdklib-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find repository-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools:repository:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/30.3.1/repository-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find gradle-api-7.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/7.3.1/gradle-api-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find builder-test-api-7.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/7.3.1/builder-test-api-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find ddmlib-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/30.3.1/ddmlib-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find aaptcompiler-7.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aaptcompiler/7.3.1/aaptcompiler-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find aapt2-proto-7.3.1-8691043.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.3.1-8691043).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/7.3.1-8691043/aapt2-proto-7.3.1-8691043.jar
   > Could not find crash-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/30.3.1/crash-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find tracker-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/30.3.1/tracker-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find shared-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/30.3.1/shared-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find lint-typedef-remover-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-typedef-remover:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-typedef-remover/30.3.1/lint-typedef-remover-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find databinding-compiler-common-7.3.1.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/7.3.1/databinding-compiler-common-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common-7.3.1.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/7.3.1/databinding-common-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find baseLibrary-7.3.1.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/7.3.1/baseLibrary-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find layoutlib-api-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/30.3.1/layoutlib-api-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto/30.3.1/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find android-device-provider-gradle-proto-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-gradle-proto:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-device-provider-gradle-proto/30.3.1/android-device-provider-gradle-proto-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto/30.3.1/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto/30.3.1/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto/30.3.1/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto/30.3.1/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find builder-model-7.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/7.3.1/builder-model-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find dvlib-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/30.3.1/dvlib-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find common-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools:common:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/30.3.1/common-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find apkzlib-7.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/7.3.1/apkzlib-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find protos-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/30.3.1/protos-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find signflinger-7.3.1.jar (com.android:signflinger:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/signflinger/7.3.1/signflinger-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find zipflinger-7.3.1.jar (com.android:zipflinger:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/7.3.1/zipflinger-7.3.1.jar
   > Could not find annotations-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:30.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/30.3.1/annotations-30.3.1.jar
   > Could not find apksig-7.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:7.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/7.3.1/apksig-7.3.1.jar
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Please guide me how can I solve this problem?
I searched a lot about this error but I didn't find a solution to solve it